# Linking to internal pages from the overlay

Tags: uri, modal-dialogs, dashboard

I have set up a dashboard to work as a main hub for all things related to my current site. I have quick links to internal pages on my site. I would like to know how I can link to those pages from the overlay without having to setup an absolute url for every link? I'm working on a local instance but will eventually have to push it live so every absolute link will have to change.. and that sucks.

Thanks!